# How to determining size for android on CSS to make it fit on a screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, orientation

I need help with CSS this time. I'm posting these images for you to understand my problems.

[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0enNC.png)

[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgaQt.png)

I'm trying to make it compatible with my android's true size. Since I am new to designing for phones, I have problems with determining screen size. Is there a way for me to make it all round up in one screen? Also, is there a way to make my screen automatically change the phone orientation to landscape when a user goes to this page?

I want to give you a block of my css codes but it's kinda difficult to read when pasting in here.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can get runtime Display's Width & Height

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

In a view you need to do something like this:

```
((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager()
                     .getDefaultDisplay()
                     .getMetrics(displayMetrics);
```

To align with current SDK backward compatibility from deprecated methods:

```
int Measuredwidth = 0;  
int Measuredheight = 0;  
Point size = new Point();
WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)    {
w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
Measuredwidth = size.x;
Measuredheight = size.y; 
}else{
Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay(); 
Measuredwidth = d.getWidth(); 
Measuredheight = d.getHeight(); 
}
```

In the Manifest, you can set the screenOrientation to landscape. It would look something like this in the XML:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
...
</activity>
```

Comment: thanks for reply..my apology for not inform these before..i am using ionic and not android studio. How to change the orientation using ionic?

Answer (score 0):

First step is to put the appropriate meta tag in the `<head>` of your html:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

That should make your page at least aware of the window size it exists in. Making the design look good on various screen sizes is another story; the general approach for that is to use fluid dimensions (think `width: 100%` instead of `width: 800px`) and media queries (like `@media (max-width: 480px) { ...css rules for small screens go here... }`) in your css.

Comment: thanks for reply. it works by changing the px format to %. By any means, do you know how to make user screen fix to landscape when user go to that page?

Comment: No, I don't think that's really possible (or a good user experience) - control of device orientation is up to the user, not the site they're viewing.